# Convert .txt file in UCS-2 file format

Tags: java, file-format

I have .txt file and i want to convert this file to UCS-2 format
what should be correct way to convert 
File is about 700mb so can not open in Notepad ++ n convert

Please suggest .

Comment: Depends on the original file encoding!

Comment: There is no such character encoding as ANSI. Do you mean ASCII?

Comment: *whenever I am opening small file of same in notepad++ is shows encode in ANSI*

Comment: Well, Notepad++ is wrong. There is _no_ such character encoding as ANSI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, first of all: Notepad++ shows ANSI, and ANSI is not a character encoding. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084124) and various others, it appears that it is Windows-1252.

As to [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2), it has been superseded by UTF-16 which can encode more code points. Anyway, at the time UCS-2 was defined, it encoded more code points than Windows-1252, so using UTF-16 is OK here.

However, UTF-16, as USC-2 did, depends on endianness. We will assume little endian here.

Therefore:

```
final Path src = Paths.get("/path/to/original/file.txt")
final Path dst = Paths.get("/path/to/destination/file.txt");

final char[] buf = new char[1 << 20]; // 1 MB char buffer
int nrChars;

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(src, 
        Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
) {
    while ((nrChars = reader.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
        writer.write(buf, 0, nrChars);
    writer.flush();
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

/*this is how I achieved in java it is almost same as above */

```
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("destinationfile.txt",                       
                     "UTF-16LE");
        writer.write("\uFEFF");

        File srcfile = new File("sourceFile.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(srcfile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.write("\r\n");
            }
            writer.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```